# Custom question lists is available for testing - why?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

There is a Meta SE post title

> [Custom question lists **is** available for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing)

Maybe my question is stupid, but why is it correct? Why not "Custom question lists **are** available for testing"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Normally*, it would be ungrammatical. In this particular case, however, it makes sense.

Following it back to an original post, ["Custom question lists: finding questions you can answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer), here is how the new feature was described (emphasis in original text):

> As we promised, we've been working on a replacement for new nav, and now it's time for us to start rolling it out. We're calling it **custom question lists** and we are really excited about its potential to help all users get at the questions that are most interesting to them.

Note that it's a single new feature.

In this use, **custom questions lists** is a proper noun (name), not a common noun. It could also have been called **New Thingbot 1.0**.

Although the name contains a word that takes a plural form (**lists**) the feature itself is singular.

I grant that this is confusing. Capital letters, or some other styling, could have been employed to make it explicit that when the feature is used in a sentence, it's clearly referring to its name rather than individual words.

Nonetheless, this is how it was named. The feature is singular, and so it's appropriate to use **is**.

Comment: Not that using _**are**_ would be inappropriate or ungrammatical.

Comment: I'll go further than your "could have".  If it's a proper noun, it should be capitalized, if not quoted. "'Custom Question Lists' is available"

Comment: @MontyHarder The Canadian singer k.d. lang is a good example of "lowercase branding." I'm not saying I personally agree, just that it's a style decision that can be made.

Comment: Yes, and Edwin Estin Cummings (who styled himself "e.e. Cummings") before.  That a few people demand the rules be broken for them does not oblige anyone to submit to those demands and weaken a valuable linguistic convention.  The use proper-noun capitalization rule provides helpful information, and neither Edwin nor Kathryn has made a good case for why we should stop providing that information.

Comment: @MontyH - There are times, though, where the words should **not** be capitalized, yet the same concept applies. For example: _I thought advanced economics was the hardest subject I studied in college._ Many style guides maintain that academic subjects should be written in all lower case, but the word _economics_ in that sentence wouldn't be plural. In the OP's example, whether "custom question lists" is a proper noun can be debated; the key point is that the expression alludes to one single feature, so the singular works.

Comment: @jr Although "Advanced Economics" may be the _title_ of a _class_, which makes it a proper noun, the subject is called "advanced economics", because it is not.  There may be many different courses on the subject of advanced economics, taught by different professors from different textbooks.  Confusingly, two or more of these textbooks may be titled "Advanced Economics" and teach as established fact things that others say are false. You'll have to add the author's name, and possibly publisher and date in parentheses to tell them apart: "Advanced Economics (Williams, Dunkel Press, 2007)".